# What is U-SQL power vs Hive ecosystem

Tags: u-sql

I am looking for data points on U-SQL power compared to Hive ecosystem, what I read so far from various documentation I got the following, any further thoughts are appreciated.

[image]

Thanks,
Nasir

Comment: Check this Ignite video which covers Hive etc in the "Status Quo" section: https://myignite.microsoft.com/videos/3101

Comment: I looked at the presentation section "Status Quo", basically what it comes down to is U-SQL brings both Declarativity and Extensibility native to the language for big data processing, where as other platforms have one native and other one bolted on. Thanks